# upserting batches into elasticsearch store with bulk API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api, elasticsearch-bulk

I have huge set of documents with same index and same type but obviously different ids. I want to either update existing ones or insert new in batches. How can I achieve it using bulk indexing API? I want to do something like below but it throws error. Basically, I want to upsert multiple docs in batches which have same index and same type.

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk -d'
{ "index": {"_type": "sometype", "_index": "someindex"}}
{ "_id": "existing_id", "field1": "test1"}
{ "_id": "existing_id2", "field2": "test2"}
'
```

Comment: here you go https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: @anekix: thanks but the doc does not contain what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/someindex/sometype/_bulk -d'
{ "index": {"_id": "existing_id"}}
{ "field1": "test1"}
{ "index": {"_id": "existing_id2"}}
{ "field2": "test2"}
'
```

Since all documents are in the same index/type, move that to the URL and only specify the `_id` for each document you want to update in your bulk.